# Is there any workaround to make Android service run every 30 seconds (not every 1 minute)

Tags: android, android-activity

I have made an android app which starts a service.
I want it to run every 30 seconds. Please don't worry about battery, it is not a public use app and it will run only ONCE for 3-4 hours in the entire week when the game is being played.

Now the problem I am facing is that initially when the app starts and service starts it runs every 30 seconds as expected but once the phone is locked or the app goes to the background then android operating system does not let it run for less than every minute. It is triggered after every 60 seconds.

I know it is android's restriction.
My questions is that is there someway to by pass it or some trick that can make it run every 30 seconds.

```
public static void startBTService() 
{
    Utilities.showDebugInfo("Start BT Service called...");

    if ( Utilities.getCurrentBTService() != null ) 
    {
        Utilities.showDebugInfo("BT Service already running...");
        Utilities.sendDataAckUI("BT Service already running...", false);
        Utilities.runJavascript("showBTServiceButtons(true);");
        return;
    }
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)((Activity)Utilities.context).getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Utilities.context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Utilities.context, 1111, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30000, pendingIntent);
    Utilities.runJavascript("showBTServiceButtons(true);");
    Utilities.sendDataAckUI("BT Service started...", false);
}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You might have a look at the [`AlarmManager` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html); particularly the notes about inexact alarms as of API 19.

Comment: Thanks so much. I highly appreciate. I am highly obliged for you pointing me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using the AlarmManager. The solution I used was a Timer queued up inside an IntentService.

```
            int delay = 1000 * 15; // delay for 15 sec.
            int period = 1000 * transmitInterval; // interval to send data
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    transmitData();
                }
            }, delay, period);
```